# Chrome adds extra <br> into variable

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, web

I am generating web content to variable in PHP and i found out, that Chrome adding 3x 
 tags at the beginning of content. So i **Var_dumped** that variable and still same result.
Source code:

```
 $productsselect = '<table border=0 style="Border-spacing:9px">';
 ...
 var_dump($productsselect);
```

Result:
[image]

Is it bug? Thanks for answer!

Comment: Please show us your full script! Also since you wrote it about `chrome`did you tested it in other browsers?

Comment: Same result with Firefox and IE :( This is whole function: http://pastebin.com/1bsyQPWZ

Comment: This may be due to the fact that you are outputting a `<br />` between two `<tr>` tags (line 19 in your pastebin): `$productsselect .= '</select></td></tr><br/>';`. Since that is not valid HTML, browsers may treat it unexpectedly.

Comment: showdev -> you were right! Thanks! Browsers move that tag before table... Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing a `<br/>` after `</tr>` line 19

```
$productsselect .= '</select></td></tr><br/>';
```

Remove the `<br/>` and done!!